# Spammers are bypassing my simple anti-spam measures with the wrong answer on my contact form

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention, formmail

I have a contact form on my website with 3 fields (email, comment and spam prevention). The email and comment fields work. The spam field works online and stops people (It displays the message: "You failed the spam test") but I still get emails with the wrong answer.

The spam question is "what colour is this balloon" (with a picture of a blue balloon).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hgsubmit()
{
if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false) alert ("A valid email address is required.");
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) alert ("Your email content is needed.");
else if (/blue|Blue/.test(document.hgmailer.spam.value) == false) alert ("You failed the spam test.");
else {
   document.hgmailer.submit();
   alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
   }
}
</script>
```

I'm using [FormMail](http://www.hostgator.com/formmail.shtml) if that matters.

Comment: always the same color? very easy to bypass that ;)

Comment: You say it works..but it doesn't? What do you mean you still get e-mails?

Comment: it's javascript, spam bots probably aren't running js

Comment: If I had better coding skills I would rotate the questions but I have spent hours just getting this far. The problem is that they don't even answer "blue" they just type in their spam url or something else.

Comment: @remyabel The spam form stops me from sending the email when I fill out the form on my website but it doesn't stop spammers because I get the email with an answer other than "blue" or "Blue". The spammers just put their url or another answer in the field.

Answer (score 3):

Spam bots won't be running the script in the page, the will just scrape the HTML code for a form where they can post data, so you can't protect yourself from those using Javascript.

To prevent those, you need code on the server side that can reject requests depending on what's in the form. You can use Javascript to put specific information in a field, and if that is missing when it arrives at the server, you know that it wasn't posted by a browser.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. Your way of thinking gives me the idea that I can filter emails through Thunderbird (mail application) by deleting emails that don't contain the word "blue".